# Summarized data not expected - Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am having my original table like below, Where Student "A" is repeating twice in my raw data.

[image]

When I drag the two column into a table visual(Without any aggregation on both the columns) I see below, i.e Only once occurrence for "A". Ideally I am supposed to see two occurrences of student "A" (because there is no aggregation on Student/Marks)

Can someone please explain why this is happening. TIA

[image]

Comment: Since there is no aggregation, Power BI treats your fields as filters. Filters always show only distinct values.

Comment: @RADO Can please elaborate or guide me to a resource which will provide few more insights to the topic

Comment: @RADO, Thanks for that post, It was much thought provoking and serves my purpose, I feel if you can post answer for my question, I would be glad to accept it. Thanks